# What do you get from boiling dough

Tags: bread, dough, food-science, boiling

I was wondering about what happens to bread dough under various cooking conditions.

More explicitly: what do you get when you boil dough?

I know baking gives you bread and frying gives you donuts. And since I really don’t know so much about cooking, the one thing missing was boiling.

I think microwaving is going too far.

Comment: Alright. I just thought of grilling dough. Is that also going to far?

Comment: Grilling dough gives you pizza, at least on one side ;)

Comment: @Doragon [Campfire bread on a stick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twist_bread) - in my childhood, no decent outdoor party was complete without a bowl of dough and a bundle of long sticks.

Comment: @Stephie Cool! Does it taste better than regular bread?

Comment: @AnastasiaZendaya Doesn’t everything prepared over an open fire taste better by default?

Comment: @Doragon "I just thought of grilling dough." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damper_(food)

Comment: Don't forget steaming dough! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baozi

Comment: @AnastasiaZendaya same principle, different fillings (or none at all): [Dampfnudeln or Germknödel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germknödel)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you boil bread dough, you get a type of boiled bagel, I don't think it has a name in English. Dumplings are more likely to be made from other types of dough, like pasta dough. And while you don't have to boil your dough in a torus shape, it is the most convenient one since you cannot shape it thick and expect to cook through.

By the way, when you fry bread dough, you don't get doughnuts, that would be a different dough (although some bread doughs like challah might produce a doughnut like result). With standard bread dough, you get mekica/Lángos.

Comment: Beignet dough is basically bread dough, though, and those are definitely doughnuts.

Comment: @FuzzyChef there is of course a flowing transition between bread and nonbread doughs, and between doughnuts and non-doughnuts. I wouldn't necessarily call a beignet a doughnut, and all recipes I found for beignets use an enriched dough. I can see how you can make the case for it being "close enough" though, and I wouldn't be surprised if somebody declared a small sweetened mekica to be "a doughnut" - even though to me, these are two very different things.

Comment: Rumtscho and @Juhasz _now_ I am both hungry and itching to travel. Or at least visit a fair or street market. Mmmmh, Lángos. With all the fixings and extra garlic!

Answer (score 4):

Boiling dough gives you [dumplings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dumpling).

Comment: Except dumpling dough typically doesn't have any leavening agents inside.

Comment: Yeasted dumplings do exist, though.  Also, the OP didn't specify yeasted bread.

Answer (score 4):

Something really popular in certain Asian places are **water fried buns** *(or "shui jian bao")*. Of course, water-frying is not exactly the same as boiling, but still, they are pretty similar...

You start with your typical bread dough and some minced meat and/or vegetable filling.

1. Divide the dough into portions so that each portion can be slightly flattened, filled with 2 to 3 scoops of filling, and sealed like a soup dumpling.
2. After filling the dough portions *(making buns)*, heat a little oil in a pan, and place the filled buns into the pan.
3. Wait a few seconds for the bottom of the buns to sear, and pour water into the pan around the buns.
4. Cover the pan *(to keep the steam)*, and cook for 12 to 15 minutes *(or until all water evaporates)*.

For an extra treat, sprinkle black sesame seeds onto the buns once they come out of the pan, hot & crispy :)